# I am following youtube tutorial and now I have problem as I want to return in List but it is showing error. I don't understand the error

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I am implementing `UserDetails` interface in `CustomUserDetails` class and I have add all the methods and in `public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities()` method I got problem.

I don't understand the problem, and in tutorial it is working fine, no error in youtube tutorial video.

Errors occurs in   return List.of(simpleGrantedAuthority);

```
package com.anurag.config;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;

import com.anurag.entities.User;



public class CustomUserDetails implements UserDetails {
    
    private User user;

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        
      SimpleGrantedAuthority simpleGrantedAuthority =  new SimpleGrantedAuthority(user.getRole());
        
      return List.of(simpleGrantedAuthority);
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return user.getPassword();
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return user.getEmail();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: The `List.of()` method was added in Java 9, but you are using Java 1.8. For the solution see the answer from fr3ddie

Comment: Please read [no pictures of exceptions](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/) / [no pictures of code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). Then use the [edit] link to replace screen shots of text with nicely formatted/indented text within your question.

Comment: GhostCat i think you want me to remove screenshot, for this time i deleted the screenshot and from next time i will only  provide text form.

Comment: Well, without the screenshot, future readers have no idea what your problem is. SO just go in and copy the error message as text and add it to the question here. wont take long-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT 1** 
According to Thomas's comment:

> The List.of() method was added in Java 9, but you are using Java 1.8.

My working implementation of `getAuthorities()`:

```java
@Override
public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
    return Collections.singleton(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(user.getRole()));
}
```

This error is showing by Eclipse only or while starting your application too?

Answer (score 0):

The method `List.of()` is available from Java 9 and onwards. Check if you are using that. If you are using Java 8, this method does not exist.